# SQL insert works in Oracle SQL Developer, but not in python

Tags: python, oracle

I have what would appear to be a straight forward insert statement for Oracle SQL.  It works properly in Oracle SQL Developer but the same command will not work in Python, complaining about

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
```

This happens on the line for the cursor.execute() call. The query itself is:

```
insert into TestNamesTable (TestName, TheUser, TheProject) values ('mytest.s', 'bjurasz', 'Beta');
```

If run in SQL Developer I get a new row.  Inside Python I get the termination error.  From what I can tell its properly formed and terminated.

Here is how I construct the query in python:

```
sql = "insert into TestNamesTable (TestName, TheUser, TheProject) values ('%s', '%s', '%s');" % (diagname, username, project)
print sql
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: You shouldn't have the semicolon, but that should give an 'invalid character' error. What are the actual values for diagname, username, project; the same as the static version?

Comment: Building your query using `%` probably leaves you open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please use [parameterized statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#Python_DB-API) instead.

Comment: Correct, same as static version.  I print the final string from python, copy that into SQL developer, and use that.  In SQL developer it requires the semicolon, so I thought it should in python as well.  If I try the parameterized approach you give I get a new error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.  Would be nice if it told me which name/number was the illegal one... :(

Comment: Alex, I think I have two issues now.  One is the creation of the SQL string in a proper format.  If I hard-code the string completely I can get the row inserted properly into the data base.  Now I just need to figure out what is wrong with how I'm creating that string.  But once I have that row inserted I fail next on a fetchone() call, saying there was no query.  The reason I do this is that this table has 4 columns, not 3.  The column I'm not setting is an auto-generated integer.  So I want to query the row to see what value the DB set for me.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check out **oracle sql insert returning** syntax. Thats what it should be for.  I used the same on postgres for just getting the autogen back.  Doc isnt clear at first sight so you'll have to look around.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Between all this and some help locally I've got everything running.  :)  Question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# These are just random definitions, must be of type table requires
diagname = "DEFINE HERE"
username = "SOMEBODY"
project = "PROJECT NAME"

# Assuming you've defined your connection before
cursor.execute("""insert into TestNamesTable (TestName, TheUser, TheProject) values (:diagname, :username, :project)""",
{"diagname": diagname,    #cx_Oracle likes this bind-variable looking syntax
 "username": username.
 "project": project})
connection.commit()
```